# Drupal 7: Printing Taxonomy Fields in Page.tpl.php

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

If you have a field that is on a node, you can use the following code to print the field in your page.tpl.php file:

```
<?php print $node->field_intro['und'][0]['value'];?>
```

How would you print the same field that is attached to a taxonomy page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$tid = $node->field_intro['und'][0]['tid'];` to get the Tid number and then call `taxonomy_term_load($tid)`.  Once there, use `print_r()` to figure out how to get at the data you want.

```
<?php 
     $tid = $node->field_intro['und'][0]['tid'];
     print_r(taxonomy_term_load($tid));
?>
```